# baposter headerbox title exceeds line in title and gets cropped

Tags: baposter

I have a three column poster and I need to have a certain headerbox with a title that spans over multiple lines. I managed to put more text than what can be held in a column, however I get a really big margin at the top of the title.

This is what I did:

```
\headerbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]
Task-Based Programming \\
model and Runtime System
\end{minipage}
}
{boxheaderheight=0.06\textheight,name=significance,column=2, span=1,row=0}{...}
```

I tried playing with negative vertical space (both `\vspace` and `\vspace*`), however I could not fix it. Google hasn't helped either, I would really appreciate any suggestions.